# Почему 1436/1005 = 1?

Tags: c#

Вот скрин куска код в режиме отладки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему `1436/1005 = 1`?

Comment: а сколько по-Вашему должно быть? *Hint:* сначала вычисляется то, что справа.

Comment: Патамушта INT. Целочисельное деление не умеет давать нецелые результаты. Преобразуйте любой из операндов во FLOAT явно.

Comment: потому что тип int -целочисленный тип! Проще говоря, вы берете целое от 1436/1005, если хотите дробное, то приведите все к double или float

Answer (score 9):

Высота и ширина изображения хранится в int, деля 2 int значения вы получите в любом случае int. Чтобы получить дробное значение приведите любое значение к float или double:

```
float kt = (float)pImage.originalImg.Height / pictureBox.Image.Height;
```